# DynamSoft Barcode Reader Dll

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

I am using Dynamsoft Barcode Readeing Dll In My Barcode Reader Project.I am getting Correct Output Of Given Barcode at Running Time But With Output I am getting License error.How can I solve it...Just I am only using Barcode dll..

Here With I have Attached That Output screenshot And code...

[`License Error Screen Shot`

```
{
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
    public String BarcodePathAndName = "";
    int i = 0, n = 0;
    public bool nextimgs = true;
    ThreadClassnextImage obj = new ThreadClassnextImage();
    public Barcodes()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        obj.BcH += obj_BcH;
    }

    private void obj_BcH(Image BarcodeNextImages, string barcodeImagePath)
    {


        rTbBarCodeResults.Text = "";
        PbLoadBarcodeImage.Image = BarcodeNextImages;
        watch.Reset();
        watch.Start();  
        BarcodeResult[] result = reader.DecodeFile(barcodeImagePath);
        n = result.Length;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            BarcodeResult barcode = result[i];
            rTbBarCodeResults.Text = rTbBarCodeResults.Text + barcode.BarcodeFormat.ToString() + "\r\n";
            rTbBarCodeResults.Text = rTbBarCodeResults.Text + barcode.BarcodeText + "\r\n";
            rTbBarCodeResults.Text = rTbBarCodeResults.Text + barcode.BarcodeData.ToString() + "\r\n";
            watch.Stop();
            rTbBarCodeResults.Text += "\n\nTotal Sec: " + watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds+"\r\n";
            rTbBarCodeResults.Text+="\r\nTotal Minutes: "+watch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes+"\r\n";
        rTbBarCodeResults.Text+="\r\nTotal Mill Seconds: "+watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds+"\r\n";
          rTbBarCodeResults.Text+="\r\nTotal Nano Seconds:"+watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds*1000000+"\r\n";


        } 
    }`
```

`][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czEOH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamsoft Barcode Reader is a commercial software. You have to set a valid license, trial or full, as follows:

```
BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader { LicenseKeys = "t0260NQAAAFUZbbNi3xJ4oViu+0+5Eim8wPzn6GeJZrIvrb/HLjzJ8Mn+GRjbfdoa/f+iRLzKTudXVEkKqj9tKlzzDP+xKzZ2IdknzMXimKDmKBivdKTXM3T5ACPK25omqoQkqNw00zExtCrR532mHig0QU6dsF5EmvkgDLxsbWw/M54wj1F1pGagM7YfKzpLN0/qvCeejimX2nvTMfOzv+M37m+0RPsnyp20pITycnvBGyWkZ3OWQ97U8UNYl+OyyfuHymz8EcjqQm9nxvYTm4nYHERHkiXMmI6jWLgK+4+jIlcS9WLgWd8pMKkI0bZCcwmVzk5z+vuGYKjZVK/iuYIx7McOP9k=" };
```

You can get the trial license from the SDK installer.